# Spring data couchbase / Spring boot: continue execution on connection attempt failed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-couchbase

I'm trying to find a way to continue startup sequence of a Spring Boot App, using spring-data-couchbase, which would be unable to connect to the cluster set-up in the configuration.

Unfortunately, this has proven to be unsuccessful and the execution stops with this exception:

```
2017-01-16 13:14:09.513 ERROR 2799 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '****': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field '****Service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '***Service': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field '***Repo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.couchbase.SpringBootCouchbaseDataConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.couchbase.SpringBootCouchbaseDataConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3331b939]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springBootCouchbaseConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/couchbase/CouchbaseConfigurerAdapterConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.couchbase.config.CouchbaseConfigurer]: Factory method 'springBootCouchbaseConfigurer' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'couchbaseClusterInfo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/couchbase/CouchbaseAutoConfiguration$CouchbaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.couchbase.client.java.cluster.ClusterInfo]: Factory method 'couchbaseClusterInfo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:8091
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:592)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:754)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at com.***.***.***.App.main(App.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
```

I'm currently using the following dependencies:

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-couchbase</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>`

and

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
```

Thanks all for your help!